# how to merge two commit already pushed on github

Tags: git, github

I have these commits

```
eeb1995 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/1-Data-Types, 1-Data-Types) pip requeriments
dfc70f8 Data Types
99365e1 Initial Commit
382601e Initial Commit
```

I want to combine the 99365e1 and 382601e commit, keeping the rest of the history, which is something like that

```
eeb1995 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/1-Data-Types, 1-Data-Types) pip requeriments
dfc70f8 Data Types
99365e1 Initial Commit
```

that is to say that the changes of the commit 382601e are integrated in the commit 99365e1 so as not to have them separated.

Comment: `git rebase -i --root` should let you squash 99365e1 into 382601e. All your sha1 hashes will be changed and you'll need `git push -f` when you're done. Here I am assuming `382601e` really is the initial commit with no parent, if that's not true, do `git rebase -i 382601e^` instead.

Comment: @joanis thanks! additional I can add the following parameter that helps me to combine my other branches with master. `git merge master --allow-unrelated-histories`